# Running hover function Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to fix a code with jQuery to show and hide a image by hovering over a component that the image is placed inside. But I cant get it to work properly. I get error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: img

Can someone please help my to find the error to why it is not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('mouseenter', '#blog-section', function() {
    $(this).find(":img").show();
  }).on('mouseleave', '#blog-section', function() {
    $(this).find(":img").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 300px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.blog-list {
  height: 50%;
  list-style: none;
}

#blog-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#blog-section_link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#blog-section_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 20% 0 5% 10%;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
}

.blog-section_left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.blog-section_date,
.blog-section_cat {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.blog-section_center {
  margin: 5% 10% 0 5%;
}

#blog-section_image {
  width: auto;
  height: 300px;
}


/* Blog page */

.blog-page {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<ul class="content">
  <li id="blog-section" img='/image/lotusflower.jpg'>
    <a id="blog-section_link" href="blogPage.html">
      <section id="blog-section_content">
        <section class="blog-section_left">
          <H6 class="blog-section_date">datum</H6>
          <H6 class="blog-section_cat">kategori</H6>
        </section>
        <H1 class="blog-section_center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</H1>
        <img id="blog-section_image" style="display: none;" src="/image/lotusflower.jpg">
      </section>
    </a>
  </li>
  <ul class="content">
    <li id="blog-section">
      <a id="blog-section_link" href="blogPage.html">
        <section id="blog-section_content">
          <section class="blog-section_left">
            <H6 class="blog-section_date">datum</H6>
            <H6 class="blog-section_cat">kategori</H6>
          </section>
          <H1 class="blog-section_center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</H1>
          <img id="blog-section_image" style="display: none;" src="/image/lotusflower.jpg">
        </section>
      </a>
    </li>
    <ul class="content">
      <li id="blog-section">
        <a id="blog-section_link" href="blogPage.html">
          <section id="blog-section_content">
            <section class="blog-section_left">
              <H6 class="blog-section_date">datum</H6>
              <H6 class="blog-section_cat">kategori</H6>
            </section>
            <H1 class="blog-section_center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</H1>
            <img id="blog-section_image" style="display: none;" src="/image/lotusflower.jpg">
          </section>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: ids have to be unique so I would change the blog section to a class (and all your other duplicate ids).  and why use js for this - why not just use css? Also, don't use headings for styling - it makes your content less accessible and can penalise you in seo

Answer (score 0):

Better to use hover : https://api.jquery.com/hover/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#blog-section').hover(function() {
    $(this).find("img").show();
  }, function() {
    $(this).find("img").hide();
  }
);
});
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 300px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.blog-list {
  height: 50%;
  list-style: none;
}

#blog-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#blog-section_link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#blog-section_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 20% 0 5% 10%;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
}

.blog-section_left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.blog-section_date,
.blog-section_cat {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.blog-section_center {
  margin: 5% 10% 0 5%;
}

#blog-section_image {
  width: auto;
  height: 300px;
}


/* Blog page */

.blog-page {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<ul class="content">
  <li id="blog-section" img='/image/lotusflower.jpg'>
    <a id="blog-section_link" href="blogPage.html">
      <section id="blog-section_content">
        <section class="blog-section_left">
          <H6 class="blog-section_date">datum</H6>
          <H6 class="blog-section_cat">kategori</H6>
        </section>
        <H1 class="blog-section_center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</H1>
        <img id="blog-section_image" style="display: none;" src="/image/lotusflower.jpg">
      </section>
    </a>
  </li>
  <ul class="content">
    <li id="blog-section">
      <a id="blog-section_link" href="blogPage.html">
        <section id="blog-section_content">
          <section class="blog-section_left">
            <H6 class="blog-section_date">datum</H6>
            <H6 class="blog-section_cat">kategori</H6>
          </section>
          <H1 class="blog-section_center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</H1>
          <img id="blog-section_image" style="display: none;" src="/image/lotusflower.jpg">
        </section>
      </a>
    </li>
    <ul class="content">
      <li id="blog-section">
        <a id="blog-section_link" href="blogPage.html">
          <section id="blog-section_content">
            <section class="blog-section_left">
              <H6 class="blog-section_date">datum</H6>
              <H6 class="blog-section_cat">kategori</H6>
            </section>
            <H1 class="blog-section_center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</H1>
            <img id="blog-section_image" style="display: none;" src="/image/lotusflower.jpg">
          </section>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```